# Facebook link preview for redirects

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

link A >> 301 >> link B

The Facebook link preview displays data from link A. I want it to display data from link B.

How can I fix this?

I used this code for the redirect.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"></head>
<body>


<script type="text/javascript">

    window.location.replace("http://www.yahoo.com");
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In general Facebook should be following the redirects because the users will be redirected and facebook does not want to present unexpected results causing disruptive experience.

Since 301 is permanent redirect you could also use the final URL, I presume.

Also, take a look at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ - enter the URL and it will display what facebook crawler is doing.